# Get CBUUID from device

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

How can I get the CBUUID from the device that my app is currently running on? I'm using Xamarin but answer in objective-c or swift would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

use  Plugin.BLE (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.BLE/)

```
foreach(AdvertisementRecord record in e.Device.AdvertisementRecords)
{
   if (record.Type == AdvertisementRecordType.UuidsComplete128Bit || record.Type == AdvertisementRecordType.UuidsComplete16Bit)
   {
       b.ServiceUUID = record.Data;
       break;
   }
}
```

Then

```
foreach(Beacon beacon in beaconList)
{
    cbuuidList.Add(CBUUID.FromBytes(beacon.ServiceUUID));
}                                               

CBUUID[] uuid = cbuuidList.ToArray();
BLEManager.ScanForPeripherals(uuid);
```

detail here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92838/proper-way-to-retrieve-uuid-of-device